# Storage for Default example programs

Tags: asp.net, local-storage

I have this silly doubt. When we open webforms or MVC we get a sample/default program as example/exercise.

The register form in the default example in Visual Studio has details to fill in.
Where do these details gets stored?

Answer (score 0):

In Sample Projects, you can see a folder App_Data, It has a database file in which the data got saved, you can open this file from server explorer

Comment: what about MVC? model created , but where to view dataS?

Comment: In MVC, the data is passing in Models

Comment: where can we practically see the datas passing through models, Because I downloaded a openID example,I couldnt find where the values getting stored.